# Airflow scheduler unexpectedly shuts down

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am running airflow `v1.8.0` on an EC2 instance with Ubuntu. The various DAGs that I have running connect with several different SQL tables. I've had a recurring issue where the scheduler, raised with `airflow scheduler -D` just shuts down on me. When I check `airflow-scheduler.err` there is no error. In order to debug I enter the `/airflow` directory and clear all scheduler-related files with `rm airflow-scheduler*` and restart the deamon. I am using `LocalExecutor`.

Two questions: (1) What's going on and how can I fix it? (2) If there isn't a quick fix, is there at least a way for airflow to send me an email when the scheduler fails?

Comment: probably good to put airflow in Docker and deploy with kubernetes so you can get benefit of liveness probes.

Comment: @Chengzhi That makes really great sense, thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your second question, I don't think that exists in Airflow. I think it's something that should be externally monitored anyways, since Airflow probably wouldn't be able to email you if it's having issues.

Instead, you can look at the heartbeats generated by [SchedulerJob](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/jobs.py#L494-L501). I have some monitoring around this query:

```
SELECT MAX(latest_heartbeat) FROM job WHERE job_type = 'SchedulerJob';
```

Which you can use to make sure that a scheduling cycle was triggered recently.

I do the same for job type [LocalTaskJob](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/jobs.py#L2458) with `GROUP BY hostname` to ensure each worker is picking up work.

Answer (score 1):

In your `airflow.cfg` there is a section for the scheduler.

In that section there is a path to where child processes log:

```
[scheduler]
...
child_process_log_directory = /tmp/airflow/scheduler/logs
```

The relevant error message could be in a log in this directory.

Comment: that entry is `/home/ubuntu/airflow/logs/scheduler`. The logs, though, are related to each DAG, rather than the scheduler itself. Are you saying that I should find what's causing the problem within one of the DAG logs?

Comment: I would check the dag logs associated with the date of the crash. Hopefully there is a clue.... If there is no clue in `airflow-scheduler.err` maybe there is one in `airflow-scheduler.out`? Last suggestion is maybe try without `-D`, and redirect the output to a file (something like `airflow scheduler &> myfile.txt`). The reason I suggest this is that I seem to remember strange things happening when I tried running sched with `-D`